# How to change the agent build directory?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-server-2019, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

My Azure DevOps pipeline currently creates the path "C:\Agent-xyz_work\23\s..." for keeping the build output that will be used in the sub-project builds. Is there a way to set the build folder as just "C:" or "C:\w" etc? I need this because there is a custom build action by one of my third-party Wix toolsets that truncates the path when it gets too long. To keep it short, I want to keep the path as short as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The agent installed directory as stated from the predefined variables is:

```
Agent.HomeDirectory: c:\agent
```

The agent working directory is

```
Agent.WorkFolder : c:\agent_work
```

Inside this folder (C:\agent\work\builID), you can locate some subfolders:

> - a -> artifacts
> - b -> build directory
> - s -> source directory

You could use a powershell script and copy any artifacts or build outputs on the folder you want.

**Powershell example:**

```
$destinationFolder = "C:\myfolder"
$sourcesDirectory = "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\result"
robocopy $sourcesDirectory $destinationFolder /im /e
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: Thank you for the comment. If I set the variables before running the pipeline, the build output states that it is still using "C:\Agent-xyz_work\23\s...". Am I making any mistake here?

Comment: I am not sure if those values can be overridden on runtime. You can set the agent working directory when you configure your custom agent. For the agent pool that Azure provides I am not sure if you can change the default values. That's why I proposed to copy any files you need from the working directory to your requested one.

Comment: Thank you @GeralexGR. I do not have access to the agent pool. Another team maintains it. Then I guess I cannot override and resort to your other idea of copying things

Answer (score 2):

You can change the value of the pre-defined variables.

### For classic release pipeline:

Variables:
[image]

Task:

[image]

Logs:

[image]

The list of pre-defined variables can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#agent-variables-devops-services)

Answer (score 2):

The agent's working directory is configured when the agent is installed, and cannot be altered at runtime:

> Agent setup
> `--work <workDirectory>` - work directory where job data is stored. Defaults to `_work` under the root of the agent directory. The work directory is owned by a given agent and should not be shared between multiple agents.

I suggest you halt and [reconfigure your agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops#agent-setup) with the working directory of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

In the agent directory next to the *run.cmd* and *config.cmd* files, if the agent is already configured, there is a file named **.agent** . Stop the service, open that json file and modify the default `"workFolder":"_work"` to your desired path be sure to escape the path if on windows for example `"workFolder": "D:\\Data\\_work"` copy the files from the old _work folder to the new location, then your good to start the service again.

This method prevents having to remove/reconfigure the agent from the pool and leave it in place.